# Where's the syntax error in this update / join?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

```
UPDATE P
SET P.post_type = 'banner-slide'
FROM `berwickr_wordpress.wp_posts` AS P
INNER JOIN berwickr_wordpress.wp_term_relationships AS T
ON P.ID = T.object_id
WHERE T.term_taxonomy_id = 3
```

Getting this error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM berwickr_wordpress.wp_posts AS P INNER JOIN berwickr_wordpress.wp_term_rel' at line 3
```

Where's the snytax errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` does not use `FROM`. Try this:

```
UPDATE berwickr_wordpress.wp_posts AS P
  INNER JOIN berwickr_wordpress.wp_term_relationships AS T
    ON P.ID = T.object_id
SET P.post_type = 'banner-slide'
WHERE T.term_taxonomy_id = 3
```

EDIT: extra OP backticks (*_*)

Comment: Thanks - minus the ticks this does the trick. I must not have been looking at correct sql docs.